# PHP function which returns the most recent row entered into a mysql function

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for a php function which returns the most recent entry into a mysql table.

Comment: its called **google**: mysql_query for most recent line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysql_insert_id() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php, which returns the most recent key from the database. You could then do a query to select it. For example

```
$id = mysql_insert_id(); $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ".$id);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use

[mysql_inset_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to retrieve recently added rows id.

But that should be used to immediately after the insert query.

> mysql_insert_id() acts on the last
>   performed query, be sure to call
>   mysql_insert_id() immediately after
>   the query that generates the value.

If you want to retrieve it later you can use a select query

```
select * from table  order by id desc limit 1;
```

Comment: This was the answer that I was looking for. Thanks, Positive. +1

Answer (score 2):

Get the last row, assuming id is the primary key (with auto increment):

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1));
```

Comment: Same as Postive's answer, therefore +1'd this too. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $link_identifier ] )

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Maybe thats what you looking for